# How to retain a row value of other columns in Groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['bird'] = ['shikra','shikra','eagle','eagle','eagle','crow','sparrow','sparrow']
df['bird2'] = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4]
df['n'] = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
df['range'] = [1400,1600,np.nan,2800,3300,np.nan,800,600]

    bird    bird2   n   range
0   shikra  1   a   1400.0
1   shikra  1   b   1600.0
2   eagle   2   c   NaN
3   eagle   2   d   2800.0
4   eagle   2   e   3300.0
5   crow    3   f   NaN
6   sparrow 4   g   800.0
7   sparrow 4   h   600.0
```

I want to find top 2 birds with max range from about data.

I used `groupby` operation as below:

```
df.groupby(['bird','bird2']).agg({'range':'max', 'n':'first'}).reset_index().sort_values('range', ascending=False).head(2)
```

which gives output as:

```
    bird    bird2   range   n
1   eagle   2      3300.0   c
2   shikra  1      1600.0   a
```

Only problem with above output is `column n`. As I have selected `first` in `agg` it's giving 1st value for corresponding groupby value but actually what I want is value of `n` which is related to maximum range.

How can I select the value from `n` column where `range` is `max`

**Expected Output:**

```
    bird    bird2   range   n
1   eagle   2      3300.0   e
2   shikra  1      1600.0   b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first, then remove duplicates by both columns by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and select top values by [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) or [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('range', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['bird','bird2']).head(2)

#df = df.sort_values('range', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['bird','bird2']).iloc[:2]
print (df)
     bird  bird2  n   range
4   eagle      2  e  3300.0
1  shikra      1  b  1600.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also directly use the max function:

```
df.groupby(['bird','bird2']).max().reset_index().sort_values('range', ascending=False).head(2)

    bird    bird2   n   range
1   eagle   2       e   3300.0
2   shikra  1       b   1600.0
```

As jezreal mentions, max will also find the maximum string, f in your case. But when you sort it by range, it falls into place.

Comment: Check with another data - `df['n'] = ['a5','a3','a1','a3','a8','a2','a10','a9']` - it count max value of string...

Comment: Yes it breaks. When I replace it with `c` with `k` in the original data, the value of `k` is returned instead of `e` from group `eagle 2`